# How io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.IoScheduler.CachedWorkerPool works？

Tags: java, rx-java2

Here is few code snippet -

```
CachedWorkerPool(long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, ThreadFactory threadFactory) {
    this.keepAliveTime = unit != null ? unit.toNanos(keepAliveTime) : 0L;
    this.expiringWorkerQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadWorker>();
    this.allWorkers = new CompositeDisposable();
    this.threadFactory = threadFactory;

    ScheduledExecutorService evictor = null;
    Future<?> task = null;
    if (unit != null) {  
        evictor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1, EVICTOR_THREAD_FACTORY);
        task = evictor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this, this.keepAliveTime, this.keepAliveTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
    }
    evictorService = evictor;
    evictorTask = task;
}
```

What is `evictorService` designed for?
When and where it is used?

Comment: Why? Manages a pool of `Scheduler.Worker` instances and shuts them down if they are not in use after some time.

Comment: @Override
        public void run() { //清除过期的任务
            evictExpiredWorkers();
        }

        Can you please tell me when then run function was trigger to excute evictExpiredWorkers function , I just can't figger out.

Comment: The `evictor` runs a periodic timer with `keepAliveTime` frequency and calls `evictExpiredWorkers()`.